# Datasnap application dies after a while

Tags: android, delphi, datasnap

**Delphi 10.3.3**

got here Android 10 (also Android 8). Battery Optimization is off . The problem only happens if my Device is on the charger. After approximately 48hrs it dies .

I tried to solve this by waking the device up periodically (after 8hrs) . Today it last sent data to the server at 3:00 , so I thought it is dead. But to my big surprise , it still woke up at 08:00 . Unfortunately after touching the screen , to try to open something . Android forced me to close the app.

Here is the part of the code :

(excuse me for the length, it looks to be long , but is is the bare minimum , I thought I'd include every procedure and function I use in order to perhaps help someone smarter then me see if I am leaking memory or doing something horrible, note : this very same code is NOT crashing or hanging after weeks if Device is not on the charger)

```
procedure TMain.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var SyncTime : TDateTime;
    TransferTime : TDateTime;
begin
  if FDEviceName = 'error' then Exit;

  Timer1.Enabled:=false;

  SyncTime:=inireadDt(FilePath+'/Configuration/settings.conf','Tasks','SyncTime');

  if MinutesBetween(now,SyncTime) >= 1 then
  begin
    if isDeviceIdleMode = false then
    begin
      BatteryLevel := GetBatteryLevel;
      GetWifiStatus;

      SendDeviceStatus;

      iniwrite(FilePath+'/Configuration/settings.conf','Tasks','SyncTime',now);

      if GetBatteryCharging = 0 then WakeTime := 0;

      if GetBatteryCharging in [1,2] then inc(WakeTime);
      // to prevent app from dying we wake up device on the charger after 8 hrs
      if WakeTime = 480 then
      begin
        WakeUpNow;
        WakeTime:=0;
      end;

    end;
  end;

  Timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;

function TMain.GetBatteryLevel;
var
  Filter: JIntentFilter;
  Battery: JIntent;
begin
  Result:=-1;

  try
    Filter := TJIntentFilter.Create;
    Filter.addAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Battery := TAndroidHelper.Context.registerReceiver(NIL, filter);

    Result := Battery.getIntExtra(StringToJString('level'), -1);
  except
    Result:=-1;
  end;
end;

function TMain.GetBatteryCharging;
var
  Filter: JIntentFilter;
  Battery: JIntent;
begin
  Result:=-1;

  try
    Filter := TJIntentFilter.Create;
    Filter.addAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Battery := TAndroidHelper.Context.registerReceiver(NIL, filter);

    Result := Battery.getIntExtra(StringToJString('plugged'), -1);

  except
    Result:=-1;
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.WakeUpNow;
var
  PowerManager : JPowerManager;
  WakeLock : JPowerManager_WakeLock;
begin

  PowerManager := TJPowerManager.Wrap(TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.POWER_SERVICE));

  WakeLock := PowerManager.newWakeLock(TJPowerManager.JavaClass.FULL_WAKE_LOCK or TJPowerManager.JavaClass.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,StringToJString('NE_PACK'));
  WakeLock.acquire;

  WakeLock.release;
  WakeLock:=nil;

end;


procedure TMain.GetWifiStatus;
var obj: JObject;
    WifiMgr : JWifiManager;
    WifiInfo : JWifiInfo;
begin
  // ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION Permission and muss ALLOW LOCATION Services on Phone
  SignalStrength := 0;
  SSID := '-';

  try
    obj := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiMgr := TJWifiManager.Wrap((obj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);

    WifiInfo := WifiMgr.getConnectionInfo;

    case WifiInfo.getRssi of
      -49..0 : SignalStrength:=4;
      -59..-50 : SignalStrength:=3;
      -70..-60 : SignalStrength:=2;
      else SignalStrength:=1;
    end;

    SSID := JStringToString(WifiInfo.getSSID);
  except
    SignalStrength := 0;
    SSID := '-';
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.SendDeviceStatus;
var
  SQLConnection : TSQLConnection;
  Temp : TServerMethods1Client;
begin
  try
    SQLConnection := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
    try
      SQLConnection.DriverName:='DataSnap';

      SQLConnection.Params.Clear;
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DriverUnit=Data.DBXDataSnap');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXClientDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxClientDriver,Version=24.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DriverName=DataSnap');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('HostName='+FServerIP);
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('Port='+FServerPort);
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('Filters={}');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('CommunicationIPVersion=IP_IPv4');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('CommunicationProtocol=tcp/ip');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DatasnapContext=datasnap/');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DSProxyPort=8888');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('CommunicationTimeout=500');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('ConnectTimeout=500');


      SQLConnection.Connected:=true;

      Temp := TServerMethods1Client.Create(SQLConnection.DBXConnection);
      try
        FOwner := IntToStr(WakeTime);

        Temp.DEVICE_STATUS(FDeviceName,FOwner,SSID,SoftwareVersion,SignalStrength,BatteryLevel);

      finally
        Temp.Free;
      end;

      SQLConnection.Close;

    finally
      SQLConnection.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      // nothing
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Here is the log file from the last crash :

```
03-31 07:15:16.070 30336 30374 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 30374 (RenderThread), pid 30336 (rcadero.NE_PACK)
03-31 07:15:16.296 14307 14307 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-31 07:15:16.296 14307 14307 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Zebra/TC21PG/TC21:10/10-16-10.00-QG-U14-STD-HEL-04/18:user/release-keys'
03-31 07:15:16.296 14307 14307 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
03-31 07:15:16.296 14307 14307 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
03-31 07:15:16.297 14307 14307 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2021-03-31 07:15:16+0200
03-31 07:15:16.297 14307 14307 F DEBUG   : pid: 30336, tid: 30374, name: RenderThread  >>> com.embarcadero.NE_PACK <<<
03-31 07:15:16.297 14307 14307 F DEBUG   : uid: 10227
03-31 07:15:16.297 14307 14307 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
03-31 07:15:16.297 14307 14307 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: thread constructor failed: Try again'
03-31 07:15:16.297 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :     r0  00000000  r1  000076a6  r2  00000006  r3  c5d2eb20
03-31 07:15:16.297 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :     r4  c5d2eb34  r5  c5d2eb18  r6  00007680  r7  0000016b
03-31 07:15:16.297 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :     r8  c5d2eb30  r9  c5d2eb20  r10 c5d2eb50  r11 c5d2eb40
03-31 07:15:16.298 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :     ip  000076a6  sp  c5d2eaf0  lr  ef7e34fb  pc  ef7e350e
03-31 07:15:16.411 14307 14307 F DEBUG   : 
03-31 07:15:16.411 14307 14307 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0006050e  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+166) (BuildId: 8549daf46b82d53f76c6449b777e63ee)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 0003606b  /system/lib/libc++.so (abort_message+86) (BuildId: ed0f2f56655f3bf72ea2135f610dee0b)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 000361f3  /system/lib/libc++.so (demangling_terminate_handler()+178) (BuildId: ed0f2f56655f3bf72ea2135f610dee0b)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00046837  /system/lib/libc++.so (std::__terminate(void (*)())+2) (BuildId: ed0f2f56655f3bf72ea2135f610dee0b)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00046091  /system/lib/libc++.so (__cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*)+12) (BuildId: ed0f2f56655f3bf72ea2135f610dee0b)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00045ffd  /system/lib/libc++.so (__cxa_throw+72) (BuildId: ed0f2f56655f3bf72ea2135f610dee0b)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 000826cf  /system/lib/libc++.so (std::__1::__throw_system_error(int, char const*)+82) (BuildId: ed0f2f56655f3bf72ea2135f610dee0b)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 0000e65f  /system/lib/libEGL.so (android::egl_cache_t::setBlob(void const*, long, void const*, long)+230) (BuildId: 338a4d9b681c482215c94f50c9c7e1b8)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 0000e515  /system/lib/libEGL.so (android::setBlob(void const*, long, void const*, long)+20) (BuildId: 338a4d9b681c482215c94f50c9c7e1b8)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 001000eb  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (BuildId: 98c923de8a462f5fbc3bd0621f98282b)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 000945dd  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (BuildId: 98c923de8a462f5fbc3bd0621f98282b)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 001cd267  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrGLCompileAndAttachShader(GrGLContext const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, int, GrGpu::Stats*, SkSL::Program::Settings const&)+86) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 001cc245  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrGLProgramBuilder::compileAndAttachShaders(char const*, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, SkTDArray<unsigned int>*, SkSL::Program::Settings const&, SkSL::Program::Settings::Inputs const&)+32) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 001cb57b  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrGLProgramBuilder::CreateProgram(GrRenderTarget*, GrSurfaceOrigin, GrPrimitiveProcessor const&, GrTextureProxy const* const*, GrPipeline const&, GrProgramDesc*, GrGLGpu*)+866) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 001c7957  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrGLGpu::ProgramCache::refProgram(GrGLGpu*, GrRenderTarget*, GrSurfaceOrigin, GrPrimitiveProcessor const&, GrTextureProxy const* const*, GrPipeline const&, bool)+190) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 001c6dfd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrGLGpu::flushGLState(GrRenderTarget*, GrSurfaceOrigin, GrPrimitiveProcessor const&, GrPipeline const&, GrPipeline::FixedDynamicState const*, GrPipeline::DynamicStateArrays const*, int, bool)+72) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 001c68ff  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrGLGpu::draw(GrRenderTarget*, GrSurfaceOrigin, GrPrimitiveProcessor const&, GrPipeline const&, GrPipeline::FixedDynamicState const*, GrPipeline::DynamicStateArrays const*, GrMesh const*, int)+86) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 001c689f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrGLGpuRTCommandBuffer::onDraw(GrPrimitiveProcessor const&, GrPipeline const&, GrPipeline::FixedDynamicState const*, GrPipeline::DynamicStateArrays const*, GrMesh const*, int, SkRect const&)+30) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 001858d3  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrGpuRTCommandBuffer::draw(GrPrimitiveProcessor const&, GrPipeline const&, GrPipeline::FixedDynamicState const*, GrPipeline::DynamicStateArrays const*, GrMesh const*, int, SkRect const&)+166) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 00185633  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrOpFlushState::executeDrawsAndUploadsForMeshDrawOp(GrOp const*, SkRect const&, GrProcessorSet&&, unsigned int, GrUserStencilSettings const*)+310) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #20 pc 003d800f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_121ShadowCircularRRectOp9onExecuteEP14GrOpFlushStateRK6SkRect$3d75113d8bcc59e80cffa524fd584b8c+50) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #21 pc 001b435f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrOp::execute(GrOpFlushState*, SkRect const&)+50) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #22 pc 001b41bf  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrRenderTargetOpList::onExecute(GrOpFlushState*)+282) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.412 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #23 pc 001f9deb  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrDrawingManager::flush(GrSurfaceProxy*, SkSurface::BackendSurfaceAccess, GrFlushFlags, int, GrBackendSemaphore*, void (*)(void*), void*)+1086) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #24 pc 001f9921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrDrawingManager::prepareSurfaceForExternalIO(GrSurfaceProxy*, SkSurface::BackendSurfaceAccess, GrFlushFlags, int, GrBackendSemaphore*, void (*)(void*), void*)+128) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #25 pc 001f97eb  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrRenderTargetContext::prepareForExternalIO(SkSurface::BackendSurfaceAccess, GrFlushFlags, int, GrBackendSemaphore*, void (*)(void*), void*)+86) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #26 pc 001f978b  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkGpuDevice::flush()+22) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #27 pc 001b87fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrame(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, SkRect const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>>> const&, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, sk_sp<SkSurface>, SkMatrix const&)+140) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #28 pc 001b852b  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::draw(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, SkRect const&, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::LightGeometry const&, android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue*, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, bool, android::uirenderer::LightInfo const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>>> const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfoVisualizer*)+266) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #29 pc 001f4ff5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+236) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #30 pc 001f45c1  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::DrawFrameTask::run()+156) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #31 pc 00202789  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+164) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #32 pc 002025e1  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+72) (BuildId: f865daa467db141161db34e821858eaa)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #33 pc 0000da2b  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+214) (BuildId: abcd5dd14a985ca140ae57aced79ae67)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #34 pc 000aaa3b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+20) (BuildId: 8549daf46b82d53f76c6449b777e63ee)
03-31 07:15:16.413 14307 14307 F DEBUG   :       #35 pc 000619b3  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30) (BuildId: 8549daf46b82d53f76c6449b777e63ee)
```

Help would be much appriciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like I need to check if I am in Interactive mode . If I am not in interactive mode then I must do the Reports Back to the Server less often . 15 Minutes  instead of 1 Minutes for example.

And behold I started the App on 31.03.2021 14:02:40 , and it is 06.04.2021 06:11 and is still running . All other Versions with Anonymous Threads etc. all died. Only this one with 15 Minutes between the jobs survived. I've read somewhere that an app is only allowed to execute once in 10 minutes if in Doze mode. But can't seem to recall where . Maybe this was the reason why it was killed after two days when running on a 1 Minute Interval.

The code looks like this :

```
  if isInteractive = true then
    SyncPeriod := 1
  else
    SyncPeriod := 15;

  SyncTime:=inireadDt(FilePath+'/Configuration/settings.conf','Tasks','SyncTime');

  if MinutesBetween(now,SyncTime) >= SyncPeriod then
  begin
    if isDeviceIdleMode = false then
    begin
      BatteryLevel := GetBatteryLevel;
      GetWifiStatus;

      SendDeviceStatus;

      iniwrite(FilePath+'/Configuration/settings.conf','Tasks','SyncTime',now);
    end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3):

IIRC on mobile devices there is no guarantee that the Android/iOS system will let an application live forever. It is very possible that your app is killed by the OS sending a `SIG_ABRT` after a while, to release resources.

Another possibility is that there is an OOM after too many threads. The log error indicates that there is a problem creating a thread.

Perhaps each DB connection uses a thread, which is not released, so after a while, it crashes. Please remove the DB connection and try again. It may help isolate the root cause of your problem. Also try to log the memory consumption, to see if there is no leak for this long-standing app.

Anyway, I would rather use REST service over HTTPS+JSON for app communication, instead of the bloated DataSnap RAD client.

Comment: but I don't understand how can it be. That this same APP runs without charger for weeks. On the Charger for only 2 Days . I am doing everything the same way.

Comment: While on a charger Android is more likely to install updates and run maintenance tasks which could be causing some RAM / resource pressure.

Comment: pfff . Even though updates are not possible because no internet. But the Maintenance tasks might be true :(
Anyway right now I created a new version of the software where I check if I am on the Charger I report home every 15 minutes instead of every Minute. If this makes a change good if not that is also good. Than I will simply stop sending reports back if I am on the charger for a day without any movement.